# Выложил приложение и не могу найти в Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Выложил приложение и не могу найти в Google Play.  Когда из консоли разработчика жму на открыть в Google Play.Пишет.

> We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: та не волнуйся, скоро появится) там 24 часа на добро)

Comment: оно появится через некоторое время

Comment: в течении 4 часов должно появиться.

Answer (score 4):

*Перенесем комментарии в ответ*

Оно должно появиться через некоторое время (4 - 24 часа)